# MySQL: inserting data into a subset of rows within a table

Tags: mysql, insert

Basically, I'd like to do something like the following. i.e. place all strings "USA" with "US."

```
insert into table (column1) values ('US') WHERE << column1 = 'USA' >>
```

What is the correct query to perform the the above? This is within the same table.

Comment: Yeah.. but how do you perform this with an INSERT query?

Comment: An `INSERT` query does _not_ have a `WHERE` clause. Take a look at Guttsy's answer if you are looking for a replacing of the string `USA` with `US` for all the records which have the `column1 = 'USA'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
update table set column1 = 'US' where column1 = 'USA';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column1) VALUES ('US') WHERE id IN (SELECT column1 FROM my_table WHERE column1 = 'USA')
```

Mind you this query makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: is "id" supposed to the column name?